# Java equivalent to Delphi's DBCtrlGrid?

Tags: java, delphi, data-binding

Is there a Java Swing component equivalent to Delphi's `TDBCtrlGrid`? Or can the same effect be achieved programmatically and if so, how?

`TDBCtrlGrid` is a database enabled grid where each cell can be populated by a number of data-aware components. The grid shows one cell for each row in the query bound to the grid, and the components are bound to the values of the fields in that row. The lower half in the image shown below (picked at random from the internet) demonstrates a `TDBCtrlGrid` in the lower half of the form.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various GUI kits for Java use a very different way of binding to data than the Delphi TDataSet/TDataSource/TDataLink/Data-Aware-Components path.

So: no, you won't find this in the Java world.
But you might find similar things when you search for [Java UI data binding](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+UI+data+binding).

--jeroen

Comment: I have been able to bind a query to a jTable and to simple components like a text field. What should I look for to be able to have multiple panels each tied to a different row?

Comment: I'm not sure; it has been way to long I have done serious Java. I'd start looking at how Grid data binding in Java works, then extend that to a parent other controls

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have this most useless bounty (didn't earn a single comment), and you at least pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm sorry you didn't get more help; I don't feel I deserve the bounty as my help was very minimal. Did my help lead you to finding a good solution?

Comment: I split the problem into two problems: the GUI was just having a panel with dynamically added subpanels and a good layout; the data update of the subpanels is using a modified TableModel. The second part is where your advice did help. I might post a solution here when I have the time. At the moment I am too busy at work.

Comment: If you find time: please do. In the mean time, your comment should get other people going when they are in the same position as you.